Can any meaning be given to a path integral with no fixed end point?
A path integral has the interpreted as the probability a particle goes from $A$ to $B$ in time $t$. Such a path integral is given by
$$\langle x_B, t|x_A, 0\rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \int_{\textrm{paths } x(s)\\ x(0) = A\\ x(t) = B} e^{iS}\mathcal{D}x.$$
However I also see, for example on Wikipedia, path integrals where the final point is not fixed:
$$\frac{1}{Z} \int_{\textrm{paths } x(s)\\ x(0) = A} e^{iS}\mathcal{D}x. \tag{1}$$
What is the interpretation of the path integral when the final point is not fixed?

Intead of a $\psi(x_{\rm final})$ number, it is a function $\psi $of the unstated endoint. When an $x$ is chosen you get the wavefunction  $\psi(x,t)= \langle x|\psi(t)\rangle$. In other words,  the unfixed path integral defines the state $|\psi(t)\rangle$

Thank you, so the path integral with no fixed endpoint acting on a state $\psi$ is just the time evolution of $\psi$? If so, I have two follow up questions. 1. If (1) in my post acts on a state $\psi$, then how do we interpret the condition $x(0) = A$? Does this mean we consider the time evolution of $\psi(A, 0)$, that is, at the point $x = a$? 2. Can any meaning be given to the path integral if there is no state function in the integrand and only $e^{iS}$?

The PI is not on operator acting on a state so I don't know what you mean. Also what does 'no state function in the integrand" mean?

Sorry I worded that poorly. What I meant is on the wiki they give the following: $$\psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{X} \int_{x(0) = x} \mathcal{D}x e^{iS[x, \dot{x}]}\psi_0(x(t)).$$ In view of this, it seems the path integral is the time evolution of $\psi$ at the spatial point $x$. For my second question, I meant how do we interpret the path integral when there is no $\psi$ in the integrand.

I understand what you mean now: $\psi(x,t)=\int dx_0\langle x,t|x_0, t_0\rangle\langle x_0|\psi(t_0)\rangle$

Thank you. So to put this into words, suppose we start with a state $\psi$ and we would like to evaluate it at a point $x_0$ at time $t$ in the future. Then the path integral says this is equivalent to taking the sum/integral over all paths $x(s)$ which start at $x(0) = x_0$ and where each term in the sum/integral is weighted by $e^{iS(x(s), 0, t)}\psi(x(t))$. Is this correct?
